# Worldsheet symmetry vs Lorentz symmetry

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, variational-calculus

In string theory, consider the following variation of the worldsheet coordinate $$\delta z = \epsilon(z)$$ This induces the following variation in the target space coordinates $$\delta X^{\mu} = \epsilon(z) \partial X^{\mu} \equiv V^{\mu}$$ Now, shouldn't this induce a variation in the target space metric (Minkowaski metric) as follows
$$\delta\eta_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}V_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}V_{\mu}$$

Why is this step seemingly ignored ? Unless it is implicitly assumed that $V^{\mu}$ preserves the metric and hence corresponds to Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: As far as i understand this change is compensated by the corresponding Weyl gauge transformation

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator Is that so ? Please tell me a reference where this is mentioned so that I may look at this a little more closely.

Comment: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string.pdf - page 39, it is claimed, that any reparametrisation $\sigma_+ \rightarrow \tilde{\sigma}_+(\sigma_+), \sigma_- \rightarrow \tilde{\sigma}_- (\sigma_-)$ can be undone by Weyl transformation, because it simply multiplies the metric by overall factor $\Omega^2 (\sigma)$.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator That is for the worldsheet  metric. I am talking about the space-time metric.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a infinitesimal reparametrization of $X^\mu$ in terms of the $\sigma^a$. It's not a change in space-time, it's a change in your description from the worldsheet of the spacetime. In other words, the diffeomorphism isn't acting on $X^\mu$, it's over the $\sigma^a$ only.